# Judy Array judysl(3) strange behavior

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I'm testing the judy arrays implementation on ubuntu 11.10 "libjudy-dev".

I'm encounter with a strange behavior, possible bug. related to the size of val and the key.

In the example, if i use the struct TEST with only 1 int with large keys works, but if i use the 10 int struct with the same key it doesn't, the 10 int struct works ok with small keys.

[judy manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/judysl)

In the man page said that the string can be any size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Judy.h>

/*struct TEST {
    unsigned int size9;
};*/

struct TEST {
    unsigned int size0;
    unsigned int size1;
    unsigned int size2;
    unsigned int size3;
    unsigned int size4;
    unsigned int size5;
    unsigned int size6;
    unsigned int size7;
    unsigned int size8;
    unsigned int size9;
};


int main()
{
    struct TEST *val;
    char key[1024];
    Pvoid_t array = NULL;

    //strcpy(key, "0123456789_0123456789");
    strcpy(key, "0123456789_0123456789_0123456789");


    JSLI(val, array, key);

    val->size9 = 10;

    val = NULL;

    JSLG(val, array, key);

    if(val == NULL) {
        printf("NULL\n");
    } else {
        printf("%u\n", val->size9);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JudySL "maps" a string to a word in RAM.  This word is used as a "word_t" or a "pointer to more memory".  The routines return (val in your case) a pointer to the word available for your use.

Your code makes that pointer (val) a pointer to a struct of greater size than one word -- thus
destroying part of the internal Judy data structure with the statement "val->size9 = 10;".
Keep in mind that the "key" is a string, and the PValue is a pointer to an object of size word.  If you want *PValue to point to struct TEST and it is bigger than a word_t then memory must be allocated for it.  Your test program seems to want to map a string to a struct TEST--
struct TEST is bigger than a word_t.

Doug Baskins